How to resize a text filed so that is displayed with new lines
Is it possible to query text into a text field in Maya UI so that it is displayed with new lines after each object compared to one long continuous line?
I would like to display in a text Field a selection of verts, each on its own line not one long continues line. Makes it very hard to read and its not pretty. And pretty is just as important as function.
This is what I have so far but I can't seem to get the display in new lines after each vert.
import maya.cmds as cmds

def get_selected_vertices():
    # Get selected vertices
    selected_vertices = cmds.ls(selection=True, flatten=True)

    # Get world positions of selected vertices
    vertex_positions = [cmds.pointPosition(vertex, world=True) 
    for vertex 
        in selected_vertices]

    return vertex_positions

def display_selected_verts(*args):
    # Get selected vertices and their positions
    vertex_positions = get_selected_vertices()

    # Clear existing text field content
    cmds.textField("vertexTextField", edit=True, text="")

    # Display vertex positions in the text field
    for pos in vertex_positions:
        cmds.textField("vertexTextField", edit=True, insertText=str(pos) + "\n")

#def create_ui():
# Create UI window

cmds.window(window_name, title="Selected Vertices Display", widthHeight=(300, 200))
cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

# Create text field to display selected vertex positions
cmds.text(label="Selected Vertices Positions:")
cmds.textField("vertexTextField", editable=False, height=100, width = 10)

# Create button to display selected vertices
cmds.button(label="Display Selected Vertices", command=display_selected_verts)

cmds.showWindow()


Another artist on discord has showed me the light. The textField is only design to handle single lines only. What I needed is something that can handle multiple lines and be able to scroll. So there is a command called scrollField this allows for multiple lines and the ability to scroll.
I just changed textField to scrollField and the tool worked.
